# How to append data to ol li using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I need to append data to already existing ordered list (ol li).but i cant append using below mentioned function could you please anyone help me

here is my ol li :

```
<ol class="dd-list" id="classroomdatalist">
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="2">
        <div class="dd-handle classroom_side-bdr"><b>Classroom</b></div>
        <c:forEach items="${records.cList}" var="records1">
            <ol class="dd-list" id="classroomlist${records1.classroomID}">
        <li id="cs1" class="dd-item" data-id="3" value="${records1.levelID}">
                    <div class="dd-handle">
                        <a href="javascript:classroomShow(${records1.classroomID})" id ="classroomName${records1.classroomID}"> ${records1.videoFile}</a>
            <img class="delete_img" alt="" src="../resources/images/Trash.png" title="delete" id="delete_btn"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#windowTitleconfirmation" onclick="javascript:deleteValues(${records1.classroomID},'classroom')">
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </c:forEach>
    </li>
</ol>
```

here is my append javascript function

```
function classroomadd(){

    console.log("level"+level);
    var clg = ${param.clg};
    var levelID = level;

    videoFile = document.getElementById("videoFile").value;
    soundFile = document.getElementById("soundFile").value;
    var classroomData = {
        videoFile:videoFile,
        soundFile:soundFile,
        levelID:levelID,
        clg:clg
    };
    $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        url : "classroomAdd",
        data: JSON.stringify(classroomData),
        dataType:'json',
        contentType:'application/json',
        mimetype:'application/json',
        cache : false,
        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        },
        success : function(response) {
            console.log("Success: "+response.sucess);


            $("#classroomdatalist").append('<li>'+response.sucess+'</li>'); 

            $("#classroomcontent_div").hide();
        },
        error : function(xhr) {
            console.log("Sorry, there was a problem! " + xhr.status);
        },
        complete : function() {
            console.log("Request complete");
        }
    }); 
}
```

Could you please help anyone .........

Comment: What happens when you try? As long as that code runs *after* the list has been put in the DOM, it should work.

Comment: but it didnt work,didnt append the data

Comment: Are you including the jQuery library at the top of the page/above this jQuery code?

Comment: can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5VWSh/ - this is working absolutely fine @VSN

Comment: yes i have included all required jquery libraries

Comment: Please see link, its absolutely fine

Comment: Check if you missed to call the js inside `document.ready`

Comment: @Andy Holmes thanks for your help but in my case it  not working

Comment: @VSN Show us what you currently have, not some tiny snippet that doesn't reproduce the error.  And "Not working" is not a problem description.  Check your console for any error messages, and post them here, _though not in the comments!_

Comment: @VSN That code *is* working, so i think you need to show us a bit more code as that is absolutely fine

Comment: I have updated my code,now its full code

Comment: @VSN This isn't your full code; where do you execute that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you include jQuery library twice. You have:

- jquery-1.8.3.js
- jquery-1.3.2.min.js <- remove this one

Keep only one and use the code provided by @SkyBuzz:

```
var data = "Some data";
$( "#myId" ).append($('<li/>').html(data));
```

Comment: I have already included these two libraries jquery-1.8.3.js,jquery-1.3.2.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var data="sample";
$("#sampledatalist").append($('<li/>').html(data));
```

I hope this solves your problem.

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/92z6b/)

And make sure you have added the jquery library at the top.

Comment: @VSN see the demo is working fine. If it is not working for you, then there should be some error in your file. Check in your console

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you answered without knowing the full picture.  If the above code 'isn't working' for the OP, then something else is amiss.

Comment: @Daedalus may be I gave him the proper way of adding the contents without concatenating .

Comment: Like I said, _I didn't downvote_, I was just offering an idea as to why one may have occurred.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't call that way 'proper', its actually slower than `document.createElement` because jquery has to figure out it isn't a css selector.